# PHP(SLIM) ошибка запроса к БД

Tags: php, sql, slim

имеется код:

```
function registerUser($login, $email, $password, $phone)
    {
        if (!$this->isUserExistLogin($login)) {
            if(!$this->isUserExistEmail($email)) {
                if(!$this->isUserExistPhone($phone)){
                    $password = md5($password);
                    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO user (login, email, password, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
                    $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $login, $email, $password, $phone);
                    if ($stmt->execute())
                        return USER_CREATED;
                    return USER_CREATION_FAILED;
                }
                return USER_EXIST_PHONE;
            }
            return USER_EXIST_EMAIL;
        }
        return USER_EXIST_LOGIN;
    }
```

Я ввожу login, который уже существует в БД. По сути должно вернуть USER_EXIST_LOGIN, но возвращает USER_CREATION_FAILED.

Помогите найти ошибку.

```
function isUserExistLogin($login)
    {
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM user WHERE login = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $login);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0;
    }
```

Comment: Обрамите строковые литералы в тексте запроса кавычками: `"INSERT INTO user (login, email, password, phone) VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?')"` и `"SELECT id FROM user WHERE login = '?' "`.

Comment: @Akina Вы ошибаетесь, так и должно быть : Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in C:\wamp64\www\Retrofit\includes\DbOperation.php on line 128. К тому же в источнике, такой же код как у меня